# Android Service not receiving Message from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have created both a Service and an Activity that need to be able to communicate with each other. The Activity should send a Message to the Service, and the Service should reply with a result.

The problem is that the Message doesn't seem to be making it to the Service. This is the output to the log from the code:

```
02-07 18:26:37.057: I/Task Timer(8850): Service bound
02-07 18:26:37.097: V/Task Timer(8850): Service connected: ComponentInfo{com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer/com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer.TaskService}
02-07 18:26:37.097: I/Task Timer(8850): Activity sent message: { what=1 when=-1d11h33m57s160ms }
02-07 18:26:37.167: I/ActivityManager(482): Displayed com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer/.TaskListActivity: +166ms
```

Nothing else from the app is logged.
Here's my relevant code:

TaskService.java

```
public class TaskService extends Service {
    public static String TAG = null;

    private final IBinder binder = new ServiceBinder();
    private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler()), activityMessenger;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(getString(R.string.app_name), "Service started");
        TAG = getString(R.string.service_label);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service destroyed");
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        TaskService getService() {
            return TaskService.this;
        }
    }

    private final class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            activityMessenger = msg.replyTo;
            Log.i(TAG, "Service received message: " + msg);

            switch(msg.what) {
            case TaskListActivity.MSG_GET_TASKS:
                // Create the response message and send it
                Message response = Message.obtain(null, 1, tasks);
                try {
                    activityMessenger.send(response);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service sent message: " + response);
                } catch(android.os.RemoteException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service failed to send message: " + response + " (" + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " caused by " + e.getCause() + ")");
                }

                // Return the message to the global pool
                response.recycle();

                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TaskListActivity.java

```
public class TaskListActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    public static final int MSG_GET_TASKS = 1;

    private TaskService service;
    private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler()), serviceMessenger;
    private boolean connected = false;

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Service connected: " + name);

            // Set the service messenger and connected status
            TaskListActivity.this.serviceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
            TaskListActivity.this.connected = true;

            // Create a new message to send to retrieve the tasks
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_GET_TASKS);
            msg.replyTo = messenger;

            // Send the message
            try {
                serviceMessenger.send(msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "Activity sent message: " + msg);
            } catch(android.os.RemoteException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Activity failed to send message: " + msg + " (" + e.getLocalizedMessage() + " caused by " + e.getCause() + ")");
            }

            // Return the message to the global pool
            msg.recycle();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Service disconnected: " + name);

            // Reset the service messenger and connection status
            TaskListActivity.this.serviceMessenger = null;
            TaskListActivity.this.connected = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Show the loading indicator
        //setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        // Start and bind the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaskService.class);
        startService(intent);
        if(bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT | Context.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service bound");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Service not bound");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Task Service couldn't be bound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Unbind service
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        Log.i(TAG, "Service unbound");
    }

    private final class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
            case MSG_GET_TASKS:
                Log.i(TAG, "Activity received message: " + msg);
                onTasksLoaded((ArrayList<Task>) msg.obj);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need a handler to communicate to the service. After you bind to the service and if the service is in the same process as the activity, I believe you could just call a method on the service directly.

Comment: @CChi I tried that initially, but when I did, the service wasn't immediately available; it started out as null. I didn't try it inside of the onServiceConnected, though. If I want to try that, I need to be able to reference the TaskService object, but I don't think that's possible since it is in a different process (:TaskService). When I do actually attempt to try assigning service to the TaskService (TaskListActivity.this.service = ((TaskService.ServiceBinder) service).getService()), I get "android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer.TaskService$ServiceBinder".

Comment: In your onBind method, can you try returning the messenger.getBinder() instead of the binder?

Comment: @CChi I just tried that as you asked, and it throws the same exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.gawdl3y.android.tasktimer.TaskService$ServiceBinder

Comment: what line number is the exception pointing at?

Comment: @CChi Well, it's pointing at the line "TaskListActivity.this.service = ((TaskService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();" which isn't in my question, because I had previously removed it. This is inside of onServiceConnected.

Comment: @CChi I commented that part out and kept the change you previously suggested, and now the Service is actually receiving the message, but now I get: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't marshal non-Parcelable objects across processes, which is... inconvenient. Is there no other way to send my object over to the activity? I need it to still be a pointer to the original object in the Service, which I don't think a parcel will preserve, will it? Although since the messages are working, I suppose another message can be used to do things on the object.

Comment: I don't see in your code that you are passing object back to the activity. But if you want to do that, the object will need to implements Parcelable interface. In addition, you might need to look at AIDL interface as well.

Comment: @CChi It's the response that the Service sends back, which is an ArrayList of Task objects. Is there a pre-made implementation of ArrayList that implements Parcelable?

Comment: It is not the arraylist, it is the custom object that needs to implements parcelable. And even if you implement parcelable, it won't work because it is across process. In addition, you probably need AIDL to pass custom object across process.

Comment: @CChi Well, I'm sending a bundle instead now, and the messages are working completely. This problem that I had was solved by your inital suggestion, so if you'd like, you can post an answer with that solution, so I can upvote it. :P

Comment: I am not sure which one of my suggestion was the answer, I will guess then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onBind method, can you try returning the messenger.getBinder() instead of the binder?