# IBinder Android - ClassCastException : android.os.Handler&MessgerImpl

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have run into the ClassCastException when using IBinder for android within a process. Following most of the online guides, inside of my service, I have

```
public class TestBinder extends Binder { 
}
```

In my client,

```
private ServiceConnection testServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                        TestBinder mIBeaconBinder = (TestBinder)service;
.....
            }
    }
TestBinder mIBeaconBinder = (TestBinder)service; this throws the exception.
```

{

EDIT

```
public class TestBinder extends Binder { 
    public testService getService() { 
    // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public // methods 
      return        testService.this; 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: you want to retrieve the Service object?

Comment: Yes inside of TestBinder, there is a getService method and I want to get hold of this instance in the client by calling this method. On a close look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder , I have not identified any difference in my implementation...

Comment: post your implementation

Comment: public class testService extends Service {public class TestBinder extends Binder {
  public testService getService() {
  
   // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public
   // methods
   return testService.this;
  }
 }

Comment: client side code is pretty much same as what i have posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Change that line to -

```
IBinder mIBeaconBinder = (TestBinder)service;
```

Since you extends the binder object you also implemets it's interface which is IBinder you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html), in case that will not work (and you still have an excpetion) take a look [over here as for how to extend the service class](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag/blob/master/src/sample/ble/sensortag/BleService.java#L35-L66) (while adding a binder to it) and than [how to bind that service to an activity](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag/blob/master/src/sample/ble/sensortag/BleServiceBindingActivity.java#L89) I marked the relevant lines for you.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the tricky part for my case is that inside of the service, I have another messenger, which is created with a Handler. So  for my onBind(), I have to use messenger.getBinder(). On client side, using bleService = ((BleService.LocalBinder) service).getService(); still throws cast exception. My service side codes look very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763088/android-service-not-receiving-message-from-activity  .

Comment: if i change onBind to return the ibinder instance instead of messenger.getBinder(), I will run into the same problem reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763088/android-service-not-receiving-message-from-activity

Answer (score 1):

The correct cast would be

```
testService mService = ((testService.TestBinder)service).getService();
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, the tricky part for my case is that inside of the service, I have another messenger, which is created with a Handler. So  for my onBind(), I have to use messenger.getBinder(). On client side, using bleService = ((BleService.LocalBinder) service).getService(); still throws cast exception. My service side codes look very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763088/android-service-not-receiving-message-from-activity

Comment: if i change onBind to return the ibinder instance instead of messenger.getBinder(), I will run into the same problem reported in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763088/android-service-not-receiving-message-from-activity